# Xcode 5. I am scaling picked images. How do I get the size in bytes of the new image in displayed in the console?

Tags: uiimage, xcode5, scaling

In my image picker I am scaling the picked image after it is picked but want to see the difference between my resulting image and the original. IS there an NSLog statement i can throw in there to get it?

it would also be nice to know what the original images numbers would be in this contex:
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(150,150);t

heres the code i am using to do the scaling:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


UIImage *sourceImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(150,150);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( targetSize );
[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,targetSize.width,targetSize.height)];
UIImage* targetImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


self.lookPik.image = targetImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the size of a UIImage in bytes like this:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1);
NSLog(@"Size of your image is %d bytes", [imageData length]);
```

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-test-the-size-of-a-uiimage-in-bytes/